# EF database migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on an MVC4 application that uses Entity Framework 5, database migrations, and the asp membership api. In my development environment I can delete my database entirely, run a package (.zip), refresh the page and all works as expected; a database gets created, the seed method is called and some default values are stuck into the database.

Perfect, really easy too! But.....yes, there is always a but!

When I go to deploy this same package(only changed the db connection string) and run this in a remote environment, the behavior changes. Again, if I go in and delete the database entirely, run the package (.zip), refresh the page, the database gets created with only the asp membership api tables. I've checked the connection string, and that is for sure, not the cause, or else the database and membership tables couldn't get created.

I am aware of using the nuget package manager, which is really a powershell instance,  but I am not using it since it cannot be used in the production environment. I'd like the package to handle it all, and in my test environment, it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Could this be a side effect of mixed migration history?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance you have two connection strings? On for membership and one for your application?

Comment: Good thought, but no, only 1. I am using transformations when building the package, so maybe there is something buried in there isn't correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default MVC4 Internet Application project messes up a lot of people. Microsoft wanted to demonstrate the SimpleMembership functionality, which requires an EF context, but it's not common sense that you have to actually modify this portion to effectively use the rest of your app.

So, a little primer on how Entity Framework works will help clear up why this happening I think.

Entity Framework (at least version 5, it may change in 6 or successive versions) only allows one DbContext for your application. Most likely, you have at least two, the `AccountsContext` that was autogenerated by the project template and the context you use for the rest of your application. If you were to turn off automatic migrations and attempted to generate a migration, EF would helpfully tell you that you need to specify which context to use. However, automatic migrations are the default in Code First, very few disable that, and thus very few ever get alerted.

When automatic migrations are enabled, and you have no existing database, EF happily (and silently) creates the database for you from your context. But, what if you have multiple contexts? Well, the other nasty little feature of EF is that it creates the database just-in-time. So, which context gets used is a function of which one is accessed first. Nice, huh? So, if you attempt to do anything like a logon, then the database is created from the `AccountsContext` and then, when you try to access something from your app's context, the database already exists, and EF does *nothing*.

So, what to do about this? Well, you need *one* context to remove ambiguity. You can still have more than one context if you want in your app, but you have to essentially tell EF that all the other contexts are database-first, i.e. don't do anything.

```
public class AccountsContext : DbContext
{
    public AccountsContext()
        : base("name=YourConnectionStringName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AccountsContext>(null);
    }

    ...
}

public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppContext()
        : base("name=YourConnectionStringName")
    {
    }

    // All your entities here, including stuff from AccountsContext

}
```

`MyAppContext` will be your "master" context, which will have every entity in your database that EF should know about. The `base` call on both serves to take EF's guessing out of of the way and explicitly make sure everyone is one the same page as to what database connection should be used. Your `AccountsContext` is now essentially database-first, so it won't spark EF to create the database or attempt any migrations -- that's what `MyAppContext` is for. You can create other contexts in the same way as `AccountsContext` to break up your app's functionality; you just have to mirror any `DbSet` property declarations into your "master" context.

Julie Lehrman calls this concept "bounded contexts" in her book, [Programming Entity Framework: DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969), and presents a generic class you can inherit all of your "bounded contexts" from, so you don't have to specify the connection string name and set the database initializer to null each time.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've added the call to make the accounts context db first, but why would that work just fine in one environment and not the other? Hopefully I'll have a chance to test this change this week and will follow up then

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems you missed the point of my answer. Making sure one context or another gets run first doesn't solve the overarching problem. You can't migrate more than one context, so if the accounts context runs first, none of your other app models will ever have tables created in the database. You need to have just one context with everything in it, and then disable any other contexts you have.

Comment: I finally had a chance to test this, and you seem to be right on... only one of the two contexts runs, depending on the first request. I'll have a chance to run the code with your proposed change next week, which should fix the issue, and I'll mark this as the answer then.The only thing I am still stuck on, is why does this work just fine in my test environment?